Switch activated by stepper motor unintentionally
I want to control a stepper motor with a switch, here is the simplified setup:

and here is the code for it:
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep, ticks_ms

def full_rotation():
    for x in range(513):
        for step in full_step_sequence:
            for i in range(len(pins)):
                pins[i].value(step[i])
                sleep(0.001)

def button_handler1(_pin):
    global button_press_time
    if ticks_ms() - button_press_time >= 1000:
        button_press_time = ticks_ms()
        full_rotation()  

pins = [Pin(18, Pin.OUT),Pin(19, Pin.OUT),Pin(20, Pin.OUT),Pin(21, Pin.OUT)]
full_step_sequence = [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]

btn1 = Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
button_press_time = 0
btn1.irq(handler=button_handler1, trigger=Pin.IRQ_RISING)

This works sometimes and I get one rotation from a button press. However, quite often after the full_rotation function is done it reactivates itself and I cannot tell why. Sometimes this even happens multiple times and I get 3 or 4 rotations. Did I mess up anything in the setup, I don't get at all why this is happening.
Edit: I added print statements inside of the handler and the full rotation function for debugging. It seems that once the full_rotation function is done it sometimes triggers the button_handler function. Still no idea why.

Do you have any hardware or software debounce on your button?

A button can bounce and generate multiple transitions when pressed (or released).
From the posted code, button_handler1 is set to run an interrupt handler on a rising edge of GP15 to which the button is connected.
full_rotation looks to take 8208 milliseconds for each call, which is longer than the possible button bounce interval. I'm not sure about the runtime environment used for the Raspberry Pi Pico, but potentially the runtime could queue multiple calls to button_handler1 even though button_handler1 takes ~8 seconds for each call.

Chances are, there is more than one problem...One problem that has not been mentioned is that full_rotation is being called from the button interrupt handler.  Any switch bounce that occurs during motor rotation will cause a new pending button interrupt, which will get serviced immediately upon exit of the button interrupt handler.Personally, I would have the button interrupt handler set a flag saying the button has been pressed, then simply exit.  I would have the main line code periodically check the flag and, if set, call full_rotation and clear the flag.

I prefer to avoid having contact closures trigger interrupts at all, and instead poll buttons in a timer-tick interrupt.

@supercat That is definitely how I do it for manual switches.  There is usually no need to react to manual switches in a sub 10ms timeframe.  If that was a requirement, I would use an interrupt to detect the press, but then disable the interrupt in the interrupt handler, and let the code that handles the press reenable the interrupt when it was done.

It looks like you have no pull-up or pull-down resistors on your switch. Probably noise is causing a false press as those types of buttons are very sensitive

In the code in the question there is btn1 = Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN) so looks like the internal pull-down resistor is used for the button connection. From the picture looks like the button will connect GP15 to 3V3 when pressed. I.e. don't think the lack of external resistor explains the issue.

I never trust those resistors when dealing with a circuit with a big motor. Always add my own 10k and sometimes a 220ohm on the other side.

Did you use a capacitor in parallel with your push button? you can use a 100nF capacitor.
Another thing you can do is to check the pin multiple times in a loop and check if its value has changed for a period of time (for example 20ms). You can check the PB status in a for-loop with a delay of 1ms (or less) and in a loop check the status of the PB. if it changed along the for-loop, break it and ignore the PB change status. Otherwise, if the loop is finished without breaking, that means the PB is pressed.
Working with motors near an MCU is always challenging, I recommend you use more filters near the MCU on VCC pins (100uF | 100nF | 1nF).
